# Analyzing disparate time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, scale, lag

Are there tools in R that simplify analysis of lagged and disparate time series.  For example:

1. Daily values that only occur on weekdays (no entry on weekends or holidays)
   vs
2. Bi-annual values

What I'm seeking is ways to:

1. Complete the missing daily values (with interpolated, or last value rolled forward, etc.)
2. Look for correlation between daily values and the bi-annual value (only the values that came before the bi-annual event)

As an example:
10-year treasury note interest rate (daily on non-holiday weekdays) as "X" and i-bond fixed rate as "Y" (set May 1/Nov 1)

Any suggestions appreciated.

I've built a test dataset manually for "x" and used functions in zoo to populate the missing values (interpolated), but I'm hoping for a less "brute-force" method for looking at analyzing the disparate time series.  I've used lag functions in the past, but those were on matching interval time series.

What Jon commented is what I had in mind:

1. expand a weekday time series to full week using missing value function(s) in zoo
2. Sample the daily value - say April 15 for the May 1, Oct 15 for Nov 1
3. Ideally be able to automate - say loop through April 1-30, Oct 1-30 to look for highest RSqr for the model of choice (linear, polynomial, etc.)
4. Not have to build discrete datasets for each of the above - but if that is what is required I can do it programmatically - I've done that with stock data in the past.  I was looking for a more efficient means of selecting the datasets ad hoc during the analysis.

I don't have code to post, because I'm clueless as to the feature/function that would make the date selection I'm after possible (at least in R).

Thanks for the input so far.  It has already been useful in helping me look at alternative methods to achieve what I'm after.

Comment: I'm not sure we can infer anything about the values during the half year in between a  bi-annual event. And if we did impute them from the other series, wouldn't it just tell us there's a correlation (which we specified)? Would it make more sense to down-sample the daily data to just include bi-annual events to see how that correlated to your bi-annual series?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Jon - thanks for the comment.  I am not looking at inferring values between the bi-annual events - I'm interested in estimating the next bi-annual event value.